# How to start audio stream from iframe after click on button

Tags: javascript, html, audio, iframe, triggers

I'm currently working on an internet radio station and I've used a classic HTML player for streaming:

```
<audio controls id="audio" src="http://stream.url" ></audio>
```

and a simple java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
}
</script>
```

which means that when I press a button that has an onclick element
`onclick="play()"`, player starts playing live stream.

Now I would like to do the same with an iframe player that is not in my domain.. Is that possible?

Here is the iframe:

`<iframe name="contenedorPlayer" class="cuadroBordeado" allow="autoplay" width="100%" height="110px" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no  src="https://cp.usastreams.com/html5-player-barra-responsive.aspx?stream=http://fluoz.radiojar.com:80/54cyaf0kfkeuv&fondo=03&formato=mp3&color=11&titulo=2&autoStart=1&vol=5&nombre=Slu%c5%a1ate+B+FM+Radio&botonPlay=2&imagen=http://bfm.rs/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-min.png"></iframe>`

If it means something, I have access to setting auto play..

Comment: Unless the iframe's website explicitly tells you that you can communicate with the iframe using a JS API/SDK they provide, or via `postMessage`, no, you cannot.

Comment: Is there any way that the iframe is muted and that after pressing the button it will be active?

Comment: The problem is that the iframe is on another domain, so your browser will block you from trying to access its contents using Javascript. Imagine if you could do it with a Facebook iframe, you could _auto-like_ your page without the user's consent. But to help you make things interactive, some websites (such as Facebook, YouTube...) give you access to Javascript APIs to interact with these iframes in a safe manner. I don't see anything like that on USAStreams's website, but spanish is not my primary language, so I might have missed it.

Comment: The only thing that could work would be to have the iframe with `autoStart=0` at the beginning, and when the user clicks one of your buttons, you reload the iframe with `autoStart=1` in the URL. But... you have no way of knowing if the iframe was already playing the sound or not

Comment: I can set the autoplay over the page I used to generate iframe when the site loads and it works very well, does that mean I could use this method?

Comment: Or can I mute the entire site and press a button to reactivate it again because as soon as I enter the site the music starts immediately because the iframe has an autoplay set?

Comment: The only way you have to _mute_ the iframe is to use `vol=0` in its URL (By the way, I've been listening to it for the past 30 minutes, it's good haha)

Comment: Thanks :D but how can I make it work through the button, maybe I will make 2 frames in which one is enhanced to 0 and the other to 1 vol? Can you make a function for it because I'm nob in scripting?

Comment: Or can you make a function that would replace the iframe that has a url from vol 0 with an iframe that has a url with vol 1 after clicking on a button??

Comment: You could, but since the iframe would be reloaded every time, it would be slow: http://jsfiddle.net/63hcx8gw/1/

Comment: Just a question: why did you not keep your own HTML5 player?

Comment: I have no idea, but after all this I will return him.. In any case, thank you for your time, which you separated for me :)

Comment: I have more questions about xml if you can help me here, or to make a new question?

Comment: If your other question is not related to _"starting an audio stream from an iframe"_, you should create a new question

Answer (score 0):

First of all accessing different pages from your page is restricted by the browser security.

Now for your case, you could make it work if your iframe is a child of the page you want to control it with.

You can use the DOM to access it using document.parent from the iframe or by searching the iframe element within your DOM.

Otherwise if your iframe is actually not in your main page, or even different domain then it is impossible to my knowledge.

Comment: See my comment above, Is it possible to do this because I have the function to turn on auto play?

Comment: You didnt answer my question. Is the iframe is within the page you use to control it?